# How would be effect gravitational field of an accelerated object?

Tags: gravity, gravitational-waves

We have a mass in space and it is accelerating until 0.7C (which gives it nearly 50% mass equivalence in momentum.)

I'd like to hope to understand the changes in gravitational fields after acceleration. So that, if the Gravity is related to acceleration, I hope to understand, a motion on a spatial dimension is effecting the Gravity.

Comment: You mean Doppler effect? Try https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/doppler-effects-on-gravity.231351/

Comment: I think it is similar to electric charge being accelerated. Difference being GW are radiated instead of EMW.

Comment: Suppose that, you are in a ship which travels at 0.7 C. As relatively, if you are  in this ship, you will determine the gravity of an object in the ship as previous, like in the rest. However for an outer observer, the gravity of this object will be more.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to hope to understand the changes in gravitational fields after acceleration.

As I see from your profile that you are not a physicist or a student I will try to hand wave an answer, though an answer exists [here](https://www.quora.com/Relativity-physics-Does-relativistic-mass-have-gravity) to an equivalent question.

General relativity is more complex than special relativity where simple formulas can be given for an inertial mass increase for a moving body, as E=mc^2. This is because the theory describes a four dimensional space, similar to the one of special relativity, but with the possibility of distortions in the four variables (one of time and three of space). This needs tensor algebra to be described mathematical, and introduces non linear effects. The name of the tensor is the [stress energy tensor](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/gr/gr.html). It describes the space time as it is distorted by the given masses and energies in that region.

The difference between special and general relativity  is similar to mapping a flat plane in x,y,z or mapping a mountainous region.

In General relativity any energy leaves an imprint in the space energy tensor. The object that has  a velocity 0.7c has extra energy and thus leaves a different trace on the stress energy tensor than the same object at rest, but the relationship is not linear.  How the distortion in space time due to the mass m at rest changes, if that mass m is moving with velocity 0.7c, has to go through the mathematics of General Relativity and it is not a simple formula.

It gets even more complicated if one wants to study the trajectory of  the effect of the mass of the object as it is accelerating, because acceleration also affects the stress energy tensor.

So the answer is  that there is an effect, but one needs the mathematics used in General Relativity to understand the specific problem.